# Genymotion virtual device loads too slow

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

I use Genymotion 2.7.2 with VirtualBox 5.0.4. I run my virtual machine (Google Nexus 5 - 6.0.0 - API 23) but my machine loads **too slow** (10 - 15 min) with this long black screen ([view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fux4K.png)).I check in a running window on VirtualBox and I get some command line in this picture ([view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6v5Q.png))

I try to fix but everything still work slowly. However, after the long loading, my virtual device **works well**, but it really wastes me a lot of time to wait it available. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

P/s: I have this issue on windows 10, but in other windows and even linux, everything works well.

Comment: it is genymotion problems.

Comment: @Singh: Could you tell me more?

Comment: why not you use live debugging in mobile ?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Currently, I have no smartphone device, so I only use vm for testing my app.

Comment: Genymotion is very slow and you couldn't test it.

Comment: I used to run Genymotion on windows 8, the virtual devices load and run very smooth. I think there is some problems on windows 10 that make it slow.